# What is Xamarin Embeded Assembly feature in Visual Studio enterprise?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

From: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

You can see that they offer "embeded assembly" as an extra feature for the enterprise edition of visual studio. What is that?

I can't seem to find a proper description of the feature and just googling "embeded assembly" returns the wiki for inline assembler and such (which I doubt is what is referred to here?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is same as [Bundle Assemblies into Native Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#bundle-assemblies-into-native-code) which meens:

> When this option is enabled, assemblies are bundled into a native
>   shared library. This option keeps your code safe; it protects managed
>   assemblies by embedding them in native binaries.

Source: [Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/188822/#Comment_188822). See also [this SO answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277105/111575).

Comment: Does that mean similar to "Application Protection with Dotfuscator"? so apk cant be done any reverse engineering on Apk?

Comment: @batmaci, no, obfuscation is not the same as embedding. As I understand it, the Bundle feature will inject the IL into the `*.so` file. It is explained more clearly in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277105/111575). You could still get the IL from the SO (but not the rest, and changing it will lead to invalid SO, iiuc). [It is _not_ AOT-compiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#bundle-assemblies-into-native-code). Obfuscation makes reverse-engineering the IL harder, but not impossible.