# Xamarin Forms "Bundle assemblies into native code" and ofbuscation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, obfuscation

I created Android app with Xamarin Forms. For release I use option "Bundle assemblies into native code". 
My apk have size - 17 Mb, without this option 33 Mb. Do I need to use obfuscation for my libraries or my code is protected?
I searched a lot - but I did not find an exact answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Bundle Assemblies into Native Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#bundle-assemblies-into-native-code) means:

> When this option is enabled, assemblies are bundled into a native shared library. This option keeps your code safe; it protects managed assemblies by embedding them in native binaries.

**Keep it safe** :

These will bundle the `.dll` files into a `.so` file so that they are harder to tamper with on a rooted device. As [BobFlora](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/69003#Comment_69003) said : it will be moving `IL` code in with the native binaries(`.so` file) so it's harder for hackers to mess with it. There's no performance issue here.

**Reduce apk size** :

This option will reduce apk size dramatically since `.so` files are compressed and `dlls` are not.

I create an empty project, we could find the difference when use this option :

- Didn't use `Bundle Assemblies into Native Code` :

[image]

- Use `Bundle Assemblies into Native Code`  :

[image]

> Do I need to use obfuscation for my libraries or my code is protected?

It is helping increase code obfuscation (specifically on Android), and there are other ways to increase security/cryptography. If you had tighter security requirements, you could use this option, it depends on your requirement.

Comment: From the link above: "*Note that the Bundle into Native Code option does not mean that the assemblies are compiled into native code.*" The original IL is still there; it's just inside a native wrapper.