# Images do not display when "Bundle assemblies into native code" is checked on Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, image, xamarin, bundle

I have a Xamarin Forms application with images (located in android/resources/drawable with flagged AndroidResource, so dir and acitons are ok). There are no problems with these.

I can see all images when "**Bundle assemblies into native code**" is not checked bu need it to be checked because of **.apk** size issue (with bundle checked = 10MB, without 21MB).

*There are no error or log while compiling and signing. When I uncheck it the problem is gone...*

The option is this; [Android Options screenfor opt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvyc4.png)

Comment: From [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=macos), when this option is enabled, assemblies are bundled into a native shared library. This option keeps your code safe; it protects managed assemblies by embedding them in native binaries. If you check Bundle assemblies into native code, Reduce apk size. And I test my project on Release mode, the image can display correct. [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260889/xamarin-forms-bundle-assemblies-into-native-code-and-ofbuscation) about Bundle assemblies into native code

Answer (score 0):

When you read the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=macos#bundle-assemblies-into-native-code) your answer is right there waiting for you:

> When this option is enabled, assemblies are bundled into a native shared library. This option keeps the code safe; it protects managed assemblies by embedding them in native binaries.
>
> This option requires an Enterprise license and is only available when Use Fast Deployment is disabled. Bundle assemblies into native code is disabled by default.
>
> Note that the Bundle into Native Code option does not mean that the assemblies are compiled into native code. It is not possible to use AOT Compilation to compile assemblies into native code (currently only an experimental feature, and not for production use).

**Three important points to note here:**

- It is mandatory that you have an enterprise VS license
- Fast deployment should be disabled to use this!
- Currently an experimental feature.

Good luck feel free to get back if you have any questions

If you just want to reduce your bundle size you can check my blog here: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688

Answer (score 0):

This is Xamarin.Forms related bug. [Bug report link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9900)

Downgrade Xamarin.Forms to 4.4.0.991757 resolves this problem.